# Control positiveness and negativeness Function

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Suppose we have a system of linear equations like

$\begin{cases}
2 x + 2 y -3 z + t &= 1\\
3 x + 2 y + z + 2 t &= 7\\
x + y + z + 3 t &= -1\\
x + y + z + t &= -2
\end{cases}$

We know the answer

$\begin{cases}
x &= 99/10\\
y &= -(113/10)\\
z &= -(11/10)\\
t &= 1/2
\end{cases}$

Also we can make any of the coefficients zero until we solve this system of linear equations.

How to ensure that functions like $2x+y^3+3z^2-5t$ at some point are positive or negative?

Comment: For the system I get $x=42/5, y=-44/5$ and $z=-3/5$. And there is no $t$ in the equations. Is there supposed to be a $t$?

Comment: Before I edited the question the first equation had $-+3z$ which I edited to the equivalent $-3z$. If the negative sign was a mistake and if it is supposed to be $+3z$ then we obtain integer solutions $x=12, y=-16, z=3$, so I wonder if the first equation was supposed to have $+3z$. I still do not understand the $t$. Is this supposed to be a linear programming problem with inequalities rather than equations?

Comment: You are welcome. Unfortunately, I do not have an answer for you. Perhaps someone else can help with an answer.

Comment: really thanks professor